# Change a struct pointer inside a function using C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, binary-tree

I'm trying to create a function to exclude a node from a binary search tree. The first thing I want to do is to find the node to be deleted. I can do that using the function searchNode, which is called inside the function exclude. But when the function searchNode returns, the pointer address of the node I'm interested in is lost, and I can't understand why.

In the code bellow, the pointer aux3 will be pointing to the correct struct before the function seachNode finishes. I was hoping that aux3 could hold the same address after seachNode finishes, so its value could be used inside the exclude function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* right;
    struct node* left;
} *root;

void insertAux(struct node** rootAux, int value){
    struct node* aux;
    aux = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    aux->data = value;
    aux->right = aux->left = NULL;
    *rootAux = aux;
}

void insert(struct node* rootAux,int value){

    if (rootAux == NULL) {
        insertAux(&root, value);
        return;
    }
    else if (value < rootAux->data) {
        if(rootAux->left == NULL){
            insertAux(&(rootAux->left), value);
            return;
        }
        else
            insert(rootAux->left, value);
    }
    else if (value > rootAux->data) {
        if(rootAux->right == NULL){
            insertAux(&(rootAux->right), value);
            return;
        }
        else
            insert(rootAux->right, value);
    }
}

void searchNode(struct node** aux3, int value){
    struct node* aux2;

    if (aux3 == NULL) return;

    if (value < (*aux3)->data) {
        aux2 = (*aux3)->left;
        searchNode(&aux2, value);
    }
    if (value > (*aux3)->data) {
        aux2 = (*aux3)->right;
        searchNode(&aux2, value);
    }
    if (value == (*aux3)->data) {
        printf("Node value inside function searchNode: %d\n", (*aux3)->data);
        return;
    }
}

void exclude(int value){
    struct node* aux, *aux2;
    aux = root;

    if (aux == NULL) return;
    searchNode(&aux, value);
    printf("Node value inside function exclude: %d\n",aux->data);
}


void main(){
    root = NULL;
    insert(root, 15);
    insert(root, 7);
    insert(root, 6);

    exclude(6);
}
```

Output is

```
Node value inside function searchNode: 6
Node value inside function exclude: 15
```

But it should be

```
Node value inside function searchNode: 6
Node value inside function exclude: 6
```

Any insights on this?

Comment: I don't see how your search function is supposed to return it's result.

Comment: I would just make the searchNode function return the node. You are not updating the pointer you are passing, so you just get the root.

Comment: `searchNode(&aux2, value);` --> `searchNode(&aux2, value);
  *aux3 = aux2;
  return ;`

Comment: Somehow I get the feeling this is eventually going to be a recipe for unintentionally obliterating a tree root with some node pointer buried underneath it. Pointers to pointers are incredibly powerful tools, particularly when doing node *management*, not so much for node *searches* like you seem to need. I concur with jofra on this. `searchNode` doesn't need to be this complicated.

Comment: `if (aux3 == NULL) return;` --> `if (*aux3 == NULL) return;`, `searchNode(&aux, value);` -->  `searchNode(&aux, value); if (aux == NULL) return;`

Comment: Eugene Sh, the pointer aux3 will be pointing to the correct struct before the function seachNode finishes. I was hoping that aux3 could hold the same address so it could be used inside the function exclude.

Comment: `aux2 = (*aux3)->left;
        searchNode(&aux2, value);` -->> `searchNode(&(*aux3)->left, value);` ... and the same for `->right`

Comment: @WhozCraig: returning a pointer-to-pointer in the search() function will make it generic enough to also be used in the insert() and delete() operations. (should be inlined)